# Curl does not save cookies if in java, but will save them if cmd

Tags: java, linux, curl

So I have this request

```
args = new String[] {"curl", "-v", "http://www.example.com/login", "-x", `"http://"+solarProxy+":"+solarPort, "-c", "cookies2.txt", "-b", "cookies2.txt", "-H", "\"Host: www.example.com\"", "-H", "\"Origin: http://www.example.com\"", "-H", "\"User-Agent: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36\"", "-H", "\"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\"", "-H", "\"Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6\"", "--compressed", "", "-H", "\"X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\"", "-H", "\"Connection: keep-alive\"", "-H", "\"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-\"", "-H", "\"Referer: http://www.example.com/\"", "--data", "\"referer=http\"%\"3A\"%\"2F\"%\"2Fwww.example.com\"%\"2F&login\"%\"5Blogin\"%\"5D="+username+"&login\"%\"5Bpassword\"%\"5D="+password + "\"" };`
```

I use Java to login to website A

The problem is that when i do it via Java it doesnit save cookies but via cmd it will work perfectly.

Comment: When you do it via Java, does the user Java, and thus curl, is running as have write permission to `cookies2.txt`?

Comment: Looking at the curl man page, it sounds like `-b` and `-c` are mutually exclusive, and if they fail they fail silently. Since you used the `-v` option, can you tell us if any warning was displayed? Do you read the output from curl?

Comment: there is error saying
milformed url :/
when its 100% correct

Comment: Hi John, I am facing the same above stated issue. It would be helpful if you can post solution if you have resolved this problem.